# angularjs $resource get the human view, not json

Tags: json, angularjs

In my angularjs app http://1ffa3ba638.url-de-test.ws/zombieReport/popup.html#/lord , i get json data from my laravel app http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/lordrest/public/posts :

in angularjs ctrl :

```
var Post = $resource(urlLordRest, null, {
    'query': {method: 'GET', headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}}
});
$scope.posts = Post.query();
console.log($scope.posts);
```

in laravel :

```
public function posts() {
    $posts = Post::get();
    if (Request::isJson()) {
        return $posts;
    }
    return View::make('posts.index', compact('posts'));
}

public function posts_jsonforced() {
    $posts = Post::get();
    return $posts;
}
```

Problem is angularjs get the "human" view, not json data. I try to put a content-type but result is the same. what's wrong ?

Comment: What is a "human" view?

Comment: I mean when it's "return View::make". Request::isJson seems doesn't work

Comment: It should be `Content-Type`, with the capital T. Not sure if it relate to your problem.

Comment: Same problem. I want http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/lordrest/public/posts_jsonforced result in http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/lordrest/public/posts when i get it with json requet. isJson form laravel do nothing and have not the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Content-Type` header describes the MIME-Type of the body content.
What you want is to set the `Accept` header:

```
var Post = $resource(urlLordRest, null, {
    'query': {method: 'GET', headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}}
});
```

and change `isJson()` to `wantsJson()` (see my comment below).

Comment: I try "  'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true, cache: false, headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}}" but its doesn't work with /posts but ok with /posts_jsonforced , so Request::isJson in laravel do nothing again

Comment: I've looked into the larvel documentation. Change `isJson()` to `wantsJson()`. isJson returns true if the content of your request contains json data (or the Content-Type header says so), but you're making a GET request, which does not contain a body but wants to read JSON.